# How to: Update jQuery dialog div with new content from json

Tags: json, dynamic, html, dialog

I am attempting to update the div of my dialog with new content from a json array and am encountering issues and am requesting some guidance.

I output a json array which has labels for a 'Name' and a 'Definition'. A user is presented with a list of radio buttons. When a user clicks a radio button which has the following structure:

```
<input type="radio" value="23" name="statistic" id="stat-23" />
```

I take the value of the radio button and use this to identify which 'Name' 'Definition' pair I am referring to from my json array.

I then use the 'Name' 'Definition' pair to populate a div which typically updates dynamically. To accomplish this I use the following code:

```
$('input[type=radio]').live( 'change', function(){
  if ( ! $(this).is(':checked') )
    return false;
  var stat_id = $(this).attr( 'id' ).replace( /stat-/, '' );
  refreshDefinition( stat_id );
  } );

function refreshDefinition( stat_id ) {
  var definition = definitions[ stat_id ];
  var div = $("<div id='definition'>"+definition.name+": "+definition.definition+"</div>");
  $('#definition').replaceWith( div );
  }
```

This works fine without a dialog (it updates just fine as is), however, it would look a lot better if there were some way to incorporate a dialog so that when a user clicks a button, the dialog will appear and they can see the 'Name' 'Definition' pair and then can exit out of it when they are satisfied.

```
$('#definition').dialog();
```

I would like the above code to show the updated data, but it does not appear to allow it.

If you have any guidance on how I could go about solving this problem or any alternative approaches, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: I found an incredibly simple implementation guide that actually ended up achieving what I wanted to do. You can read it here: http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating the dialogs content?

```
$('#definition').html(definition.name+": "+definition.definition);
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/EHmNe/).

EDIT:
unnecessary .dialog('widget') made this answer wrong.